# Cannot save to secondary drives from Firefox in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hard-drive, firefox, google-chrome, chromium, browser

I have two drives set up on my computer; the first is the boot drive that holds Ubuntu 18.04 and is an SSD, the second is a Western Digital drive that I use for storage. Both show up in directory paths for every piece of software I run EXCEPT Firefox! If I select a file or image and do save as, I cannot navigate to, find or see the secondary storage drive!

Anybody have any ideas why this is occurring, and how I might be able to fix this?

**Mount Options:**

**Mount at system startup is checked**
**Show in use interface is checked**
**Require additional authorization yada yada yada is NOT checked**
**NO Display Name**
**NO Icon Name**
**NO Symbolic Icon Name**
**unamed field has these properties: nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show**
**Mount Point = /mnt/Storage_Disc_01**
**Identify As = /dev/disk/by-label/Storage_Disc_01**
**Fiesystem Type = auto**

Comment: How is that partition mounted?  (add the mount option to the question please).

Comment: @Rinzwind I've tried both the automount on bootup so the drive appears on the desktop, and the manual mount option; neither one makes a difference. It is also occurring in Chromium (tried that as an alternate browser) Might install Chrome and see what happens.

Comment: Google Chrome can access all internal and external drives, only the 'new' version of Firefox (quantum?) and Chromium cannot. So far not impressed with 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem that neither Firefox nor Chrome would recognise additional drives in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04.  Interestingly in Xubuntu, Firefox would recognise other drives but Chrome would not. However I prefer Bionic Beaver and so I looked at other browsers. The only one I found which recognized other drives was Waterfox Web. Unfortunately this browser is too simple for my liking and lacking in features. Amazingly when I next tried Firefox, it recognized all additional drives but Chrome still wouldn’t. I’m no Linux programming expert but my guess is that Web must have provided the necessary links for Firefox. Try it and see; hope it works for you.